# Converting CfbsBitmap format to JPG

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, symbian, nokia

I am doing a mobile application using symbian and Qt 4.7

I have a CFBSBitmap data when i save the CFBSBitmap data, the format is a .mbm file and I wish to convert it to be saved as jpg format.

Can anyone help me in this area as I am quite a newbie in Qt and Symbian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QImage`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimage.html) provides a [`save`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimage.html#save) function that takes a parameter `format`. [Just specify the `JPG` format](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimage.html#reading-and-writing-image-files).

Comment: So i have to initialize a QImage with the CFBSBitmap data and then save the QImage with JPG?

Comment: @robobooga: I thought you were already doing that. Qt provides the QImage class in order to handle images, (load and save, render and modify them). My answer requires that your image is stored in a QImage, yes.

Comment: Yea I am doing that. Just clarifying, Thanks